# Load Specific Brand Products on Top On Category Page

Tags: category, product-list, sorting

I have a new store on magento. I was trying to showcase product list from a category where certain brand items always load at first.

For eg. I have menu tab called Laptops, if someone click on laptops, first Toshiba laptops appears and there after other brand products should appear Lenovo, Dell and so on.

This seems to be sorting of items. At the moment I can see Sort By: Position, Name and Price. I was wondering if can enable such sorting where particular brand items appear first.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be accomplished by using the native Sort By: Position.  This would require a bit of a time investment in manually setting sort positions.

1. Catalog -> Categories -> Manage Categories
2. Select category you want to set positions
3. Select Category Products tab
4. Change your sort order in the position column

Comment: the only thing I missed to enable Sorting for attribute under Frontend Properties - Used for Sorting in Product Listing to YES